Add GTest to visual studio with cmake
I am trying to add a GTest unit test project to an existing CMake project.
This existing project generates multiple executables and libraries.
I have added a CMakeTests.txt file to generate the GTest project and this it does.
The problem is that when I view the test explorer the expected tests are there but then the application executables run and I have no idea why.
This is the part of the top level cmaklists.txt file that adds the GTest project to the build tree
add_subdirectory(apps)
add_subdirectory(libraries)
add_subdirectory(experiments)
add_subdirectory(appsupport)
add_subdirectory(UnitTesting)

This is the CmakeLists.txt file that creates to GTest project
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(Test)
# GoogleTest requires at least C++14
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/03597a01ee50ed33e9dfd640b249b4be3799d395.zip
)
# For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

enable_testing()

add_executable(
  Test
  Test.cpp
)


target_link_libraries(
  Test
  GTest::gtest_main
)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(Test)

I cannot see what the issue is.
I can run the tests from the command line but not in the test explorer
